# How do I fill a C++ vector with input from keyboard?

Tags: c++, vector, user-input

The trick is in that I don't know the size of the string yet. I need to be able to ask user for a word, and that this word would be stored in a vector.

```
int main()
{

    vector<char> word (80);

    // get the word from user
    for(int i=0 ; getchar() != '\n' ; i++)
        {
            cin >> word[i];
        }
    // print the word from user
    for(int i=0 ; i<=word.size() ; i++)
        {
            cout << word[i] << endl;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** It's simply that I want to capture a word input from keyboard, any word at all, a string of characters, etc. Example: Let's say I want to add the word "obvious" to a vector, so that I can later manipulate the vector. So I type "obvious", then press enter, and there you go, I have a vector of size 7 with the word 'obvious' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string str;

// I'm confused about whether you want a line, or a word.
// this gets a line
std::getline(std::cin, str);

// this gets a word
// std::cin >> str;

vector<char> word(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was asked and answered frequently. The obvious approach is

```
std::vector<char> word{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
```

... or an equivalent version compiling with C++ 2003 but tweaked to avoid the Most Vexing Parse.

If you want to just read a partial input, e.g., just a line, you need to slightly tweak it:

```
for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(std::cin), end;
     it != end && *it != '\n'; ++it)
{
    word.push_back(*it);
}
++it;
```

The key in either case is to let the `std::vector<char>` grow to the necessary size.

Comment: Doesn't that get the entirety of standard input?  I don't think that's what he is asking for.

Comment: Primarily I needed to fix the use of `)` to use `}`. What explanation do you want? Vectors can be constructed from a sequence using a pair of iterators. An input stream can be turned into a sequence of `char`s using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`, and the "keyboard" is [normally] read from using `std::cin`. So, this code will "fill the vector from the keyboard".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, this will get the entire input. I also don't know if this is what he is asking for. I also don't think he provided a lot of detail of what he wants: "string", "input", "word" - who knows what he wants. His code does neither of this but seems to travel in lines.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but it's simply that I want to capture a word input from keyboard, any word at all, a string of characters, etc. Example: Let's say I want to add the word "obvious" to a vector, so that I can later manipulate the vector. So I type "obvious", then press enter, and there you go, I have a vector of size 7 with the word 'obvious' in it.

Comment: What does _word_ mean for you? Where does it start, where does it stop? If you just read a `std::string` the C++ standard has answered this question: a word starts with the first non-whitespace and ends with the first whitespace. Reading it into a variable is trivial: `std::string word; if (std::cin >> word) { now_you_got_a_word_in(word); }` (you **always** need to check that your input was successful). If you want to simulate this with characterwise, you'd use `std::isspace()` from the `<cctype>` header.